# ListView enable checkedTextView anomaly

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview consisting of 20 items, using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice as the textview layout, which uses CheckedTextView. I want the checkbox to be checked when selected, achieved by :

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, final View v, int pos, long id) {
    ((CheckedTextView) v).setChecked(true);
}
```

However, when i do this, it is not only that particular checkedtextview which gets checked, but several others which are also checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
((CheckedTextView)parent.getChildAt(pos)).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Tried this earlier, but somehow it displays weird behavior. Even though there are 20 items in the entire list, getChildCount() returns 9. So when I click the 10th or any greater item, there's a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

you can achieved this by creating a custom Adapter. All you need to do is to
create a new class that extends the BaseAdapter class.

For this to work with the layout you're using you need to modify the
getView method.below is the snippet

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
     ViewHolder holder;

```
 if (convertView == null) 
 {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.checkbox = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
 } 
 else
 {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }

  holder.checkbox.setText(tasks.get(position).getName());
  holder.checkbox.setChecked(tasks.get(position).isCompleted());

  return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder {
  CheckedTextView checkbox;

}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty much a beginner so I'll need to go through custom adapters. Hope this works. Still, any reason why multiple checkboxes are checked when only one of them is clicked.

Comment: This works great, but getView is only called when the view needs to be created again(when that particular row is scrolled out and then back in). What I want is when I click a list item, it gets checked there and then.